# Execute Powershell script in C# without UserName and Password

Tags: c#, powershell, process

How I will execute the Powershell script in C# without use of UserName and Password?

Powershell Script:

```
#Script:This Script generate the Package (Zip file) dynamically for unittest 
#DirectoryName is Out Directory of Unittest execution
#location  is Out\Resource Directory
#locationdetail is Array of files Directory for generate the Package
#FileName is name of Package generated through this script
#option is use for switch case implementation,currently not implemented 

 param(   
        [string]$DirectoryName="."
    ,   [string]$location=""
    ,   [string]$FileName="Test.zip"
    ,   [int] $option
)

 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($DirectoryName+"\\"+"Ionic.Zip.dll");
  $locationdetail =  "Package\\Resource", "Package\\ResourceBad", "Package\\ResourceEmptymetada","Package\\ResourceEmptydatafile","Package\\EmptyTest"
  $directoryToZip=""

  foreach ($element in $locationdetail) 
  {
    If($element -eq "Package\\Resource")
    {
        $directoryToZip= $location+"\\"+"Package\\Resource"
        $FileName ="Package (Good Data).zip"        
    }
    If($element -eq "Package\\ResourceBad")
    {
        $directoryToZip= $location+"\\"+"Package\\ResourceBad"
        $FileName ="Package (Bad Data).zip"     
    }
    If($element -eq "Package\\ResourceEmptymetada")
    {
        $directoryToZip= $location+"\\"+"Package\\ResourceEmptymetada"
        $FileName ="Package (Bad with ManifestEmpty).zip"               
    }
    If($element -eq "Package\\ResourceEmptydatafile")
    {
        $directoryToZip= $location+"\\"+"Package\\ResourceEmptydatafile"
        $FileName ="Package (Bad with Datafile Empty).zip"      
    }
    If($element -eq "Package\\EmptyTest")
    {
        $directoryToZip= $location+"\\"+"Package\\EmptyTest"
        $FileName ="EmptyTest.zip"      
    }
    $zipfile =  new-object Ionic.Zip.ZipFile
    $e= $zipfile.AddDirectory($directoryToZip)
    $zipfile.Save( $location+"\\"+$FileName)
    $zipfile.Dispose()
    $directoryToZip=""
  }
```

and My C# code

```
private static void StartPowerShell(string args,string TempScript)
    {

        string powerShellPath ="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
        string commandLine = @" -Sta -Command ""& {{ try {{ {0} }} catch {{throw}} }} """.InvariantCultureFormat(args);

        var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = powerShellPath;
        info.Arguments = commandLine;
        info.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.CreateNoWindow = false;
        info.RedirectStandardError = true;
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        //Pass the Username and Password here in  ProcessStartInfo
        info.UserName = "Saroop";
        string pw = "saroop";
        System.Security.SecureString password = new System.Security.SecureString();
        foreach (var item in pw)
        {
            password.AppendChar(item);
        }
        info.Password = password;
        info.RedirectStandardError = true;
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = info;
        bool flag = p.Start();
        string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        p.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Please guide me anyone. I try to use runas command to start my Powershell.exe as a User(Administrator) but it's also ask for Username and Password.
I try for System.Management.Automation. dll but it's no more existed in .Net4.0
Reference link :
**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation(v=vs.85).aspx**

Please help me.

Comment: I found the answer of my query .
  FOR EXECUTE THE POWERSHELL SCRIPT MUST EXECUTE THE POLICY COMMAND FOR 
  SYSTEM32 
       **C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe**
  AND IF YOUR SYSTEM IS 64BIT THEN ALSO EXECUTE SAME POLICY FOR 64BIT POWERSHELL.EXE TOO.
        **C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\POWERSHELL.EXE**
       
**`COMMAND : Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer of my query .
  FOR EXECUTE THE POWERSHELL SCRIPT MUST EXECUTE THE POLICY COMMAND FOR 
  SYSTEM32 
       C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
 AND IF YOUR SYSTEM IS 64BIT THEN ALSO EXECUTE SAME POLICY FOR 64BIT POWERSHELL.EXE TOO.
        C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\POWERSHELL.EXE

```
    /// COMMAND : `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`
```

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote in the comment will works, but i'd like to give you another direction to run powershell scripts from C# code.

You can use `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces` namespace which expose really easy and more elegant way to run powershell commands and retrieve the results from C# (and using the returned **objects** and not just the output textual stream). Try to read about it.

Comment: Download the PowerShell SDK, http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2560 it has examples in C# how to call PowerShell.

Comment: This Dll not avaliable in .Net 4.0.

Comment: @Shanhar,Phil : Your way also not wrong but for that I need to Install Powershell SDK. But if i don't have any rights to install SDK then it's required to run as Process.My script is run on TFS 2010 and I don't know anything about TFS server configuration.So we both are correct in different scenarios