# Unable to load .ps1 powershell script from Powershell command (console)

Tags: powershell

I am stuck in this weird problem where I am trying to execute a powershell script from the powershell command prompt. But neither do I get any errors nor the script is loaded.

I have script in `C:\temp\myFunction.ps1` (which has a method `getMyName()` )

I open the powershell command and navigate to this directory and execute

```
./myFunction.ps1
```

then there are no errors and return back to the next line in the prompt. But when I try to call the function getMyName - I get error getMyName is not recognised.

I have set the `Execution-Policy to Unrestricted`, I am running the powershell as Administrator

Comment: It would be interesting to see what you mean exactly with: the function has a method.

Answer (score 5):

Try [dot sourcing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx) your script:

```
. .\myFunction.ps1
```

Comment: Yes It works but I fail to understand the concept. I am really thankful to you

Comment: Your `getMyName()` is a function defined in your myFunction.ps1. It lives in the scope of myFunction.ps1. To have it in the console's scope you need to dot source the myFunction.ps1  file. Read technet link posted in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's basic problem of Powershell script. Set the Path where you physically saved your file and then execute the Powershell script. One more thing

```
1. start your command window run as admin.
2. set the Powershell script policy for execution.
```

Comment: Will try by setting the path .. the . ./abc.ps1 solution also works but this i need to see. thanks

Comment: @ajax: Most welcome..
you will study this link. I face same problem and I resolve it too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033847/execute-powershell-script-in-c-sharp-without-username-and-password

Comment: Hi Guys I did some extra search and found out that declaring the functions as global will also solve this issue. function Example - global:myFunction()